# how to test each element of array in mongodb subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have mongodb document with the following data:

```
    amenities[
{
    amenity_id:52,
    Amenity:"AC"
},
{
    amenity_id:23,
    Amenity:"Free Parking"
}
]
```

I want to match each `amenity_id` element of the array with particular value and return true or false using condition `$cond`. I used

```
"$project":{'Free Parking':{'$cond':{'if':{'$in':['amenities.amenityId',[23]]},'then':'True','else':'False'}}
```

If a document contains `amenity_id= 52` then a query has to return False. 
It is returning false irrespective of the menityId. The amenity Id could be list hence using `$in`. How can i test each element ?

Comment: I was able to solve this by collecting all the id in one stage and compared values with the list in next stage

Comment: Are you querying for documents that match a condition?  Or doing something else?   You can find documents that have multiple conditions satisfied in an array using $all.

Comment: Why do you have `_id` in one place but then test `amenityId` in your code?

Comment: My bad. I have updated the question now.

Comment: You still have `amenityId` in one place and `amenity_id` in the other.  I was wondering if that was the core of your issue, but if it's working, I'm guessing it's correct in your code, and just incorrect in the sample code or documents.

Comment: I'm also still not clear what the entire operation you want to do it.  Do you want to only match certain documents?  Only return certain portion of the documents?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input collection is

```
[
  {
    amenities: [
      {
        _id: 52,
        Amenity: "AC"
      },
      {
        _id: 23,
        Amenity: "Free Parking"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

using aggregate pipeline $map

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      amenites: {
        $map: {
          input: "$amenities",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            Amenity: "$$item.Amenity",
            _id: "$$item._id",
            isValid: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$item._id",
                    23
                  ]
                },
                then: true,
                else: false
              },

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You'll get result as:

```
[
  {
    "amenites": [
      {
        "Amenity": "AC",
        "_id": 52,
        "isValid": false
      },
      {
        "Amenity": "Free Parking",
        "_id": 23,
        "isValid": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

use $unwind operation in mongodb it will unwind the array field in to multiple documents

Please refer this url - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

ex:

```
{
  _id :1,
  field: [1,2,3]
}
```

this will be converted to the following using $unwind,

```
[
    {_id, field:1},
    {_id, field:2},
    {_id, field:3}
]
```

after `$unwind` you can run a match query, with `$in` query,

Ex:

```
{
 $match: {
   field: {$in: [1,2]} 
 }
}
```

Comment: The unwind  is unnecessary and it now destroys the original documents.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky aggregation  query will not modify any original document and it cannot happen, can you tell me more details about the issue you got?

Comment: The point is that the aggregation pipeline changes the number of documents and their shape (in the pipeline) when you use $unwind - so whatever you want to do with them *after* the $unwind is operating with different documents than the ones that are stored in the collection.  I didn't mean it does anything to the documents on disk, but when the question is "how do I test document for X" changing the document will no longer return the original document they wanted to test.